# Вертикальное меню FLTK

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вертикальное меню? С помощью Fl_Menu_Bar не получилось:

[image: Код]
[image: Форма]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `Fl_Menu_Bar` в качестве меню стал использовать объект класса `Fl_Tree`. Изначальная задача заключалась в создании вертикального меню. На скриншотах Вы можете увидеть, что ничего путного с Fl_Menu_Bar не вышло(не известно почему). Горизонтальные меню делал не в первый раз, а вот с вертикальным перепробовал множество вариантов с Fl_Menu_Bar Полистав официальную документацию пришёл к выводу, что лучше использовать Fl_Tree. Да и мне, по визуализации, Fl_Tree больше понравился.
Если у кого-то есть вариант с вертикальным меню, можете оставить его здесь.
Спасибо всем за горячее обсуждение данного вопроса!

Comment: @Сергей Вроде вполне является. Человек пишет, что для создания вертикального меню решил использовать класс `Fl_Tree`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, класс `Fl_Tree` нужен, чтобы "сделать вертикальное меню с помощью Fl_Menu_Bar"?

Comment: @Сергей Мне кажется все нормально. Автор видимо понял, что [пытался использовать не тот класс](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/215103).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вы не могли бы всё же ответить "да / нет" (а не "нормально /не нормально") на вопрос  "класс Fl_Tree нужен, чтобы "сделать вертикальное меню с помощью Fl_Menu_Bar"?" Я в этих классах не разбираюсь.

Comment: @Сергей Я тоже не разбираюсь. Но судя по всему "нет", вообще отказался от `Fl_Menu_Bar`, счев его неподходящим для этой цели.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  я тоже так понял. Вот поэтому ответ в такой форме и не является ответом на вопрос для базы знаний и требует исправления автором. Аналогично тому, как на вопрос  "как на автобусе доехать до вокзала?" получить ответ "возьмите такси".  Так как я тему не очень понимаю, то сам исправлять не возьмусь.

Comment: @Сергей Интересно, а "автобусы туда не ходят, возьмите такси" - тоже не ответ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, для базы знаний - нет. Надо изменить формулировку вопроса тогда или хоть ответа. Иначе на вопросы "как лучше написать на Python <что-то>?" надо будет принимать ответы "<это> лучше вот так писать на ассемблере". Здесь ответ может быть: "С помощью Fl_Menu_Bar сделать невозможно. Надо использовать  объект класса Fl_Tree" (но вот верно ли это - не знаю).

Comment: @Сергей Постарался поправить.